# Adding class inheritance dynamically

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to create dynamic class inheritance with python. For example (**x** is maybe an random number)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Test3(object):
  def sub(self):
    self.c = self.a - self.b

class Test2(object):
  def add(self):
    self.c = self.a + self.b


class Test1(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 2
    self.c = 0


if x >= 0:
  test = Test1
  ## do something to load Test2 methods
  test.add()
  print (test.c)
elif x >= 10:
  test = Test1
  ## do something to load Test3 methods
  test.sub()
  print (test.c)
else:
  test = Test1
  ## do something to load Test3 & Test2 methods
  test.add()
  print (test.c)
  test.sub()
  print (test.c)
```

I have tried different things to make this working. I couldn't manage anyway other than staticly implement the subclasses, which is not what I want:

```
class Test1(Test2, Test3)
```

I also don't want to load a object in a variable and get access about the variables name like:

```
test1.test3.sub()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tricks you can do to achieve this sort of thing.

First of you can do something ugly like this:-

```
def extend(instance, new_class):
    """Add new_class mixin to existing instance"""
    instance.__class__ = type(
            '%s_extended_with_%s' % (instance.__class__.__name__, new_class.__name__), 
            (instance.__class__, new_class), 
            {}
        )
```

You can use that like this

```
   extend(test , Test2 )
```

But I would normally prefer to create the dynamic type before initialization rather than overwrtting __class__ so instead of the above for your first example you would do

```
   custom_class = type('special_extended_class', ( Test, Test2 ), {} )
   test  = custom_class()
```

Note that in the above Test, and Test2 are variable refernces so you cna use anything here,
but it isn't hugely different from doing the following which is more readable.

```
  class1 = Test
  class2 = Test2
  class TmpClass(class1, class2):pass
  test = TmpClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you would want to do things that way. I would create a base test class then inherit different methods based off of that class.

```
class BaseTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 0

class Test3(BaseTest):
    def sub(self):
        self.c = self.a - self.b

class Test2(BaseTest):
    def add(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b

class Test4(Test3, Test2):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = -1
    if x >= 10:
        test = Test3()
        ### load test3 methodes
        test.sub()
        print (test.c)

    elif x >= 0:
        test = Test2()
        ## load test2 methodes
        test.add()
        print (test.c)

    else:
        test = Test4()
        ### load test 2 & test 3 methodes
        test.add()
        print (test.c)
        test.sub()
        print (test.c)
```

If you really want something dynamic then you will have to set the x value on import

```
import random

class Test3(object):
    def sub(self):
        self.c = self.a - self.b

class Test2(object):
    def add(self):
        self.c = self.a + self.b

class Test4(Test3, Test2):
    pass

val = random.randint(0, 3)
print(val)
x = {0: object,
     1: Test3,
     2: Test2,
     3: Test4,
     }.get(val, object)
print(x)

class BaseTest(x):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = BaseTest()
    print(b.c)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably make this work by manually setting the members of the class member dictionary as suggested by rgammans, but the easiest way would be with exec:

```
super = 'list'
exec('class Awesome(' + super +'):\n  pass')
```